# SQL: Finding the next closest date

Tags: sql

I have table like this

```
id | name | registration date
-----------------------------
1  | ABC  |     2018-01-01
2  | DEF  |     2018-01-02
3  | GHI  |     2018-01-06
4  | JKL  |     2018-01-07
5  | MNO  |     2018-01-09
```

I wanted to create a table with name of person, registration date, and name of the person who register after him.

So i wanted the result table look like this:

```
name | registration date  | next person
---------------------------------------
ABC  |     2018-01-01     | DEF
DEF  |     2018-01-02     | GHI
GHI  |     2018-01-06     | JKL
JKL  |     2018-01-07     | MNO
MNO  |     2018-01-09     | -
```

What's the most efficient way to achieve this in SQL?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`,etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `subquery` :

```
select *, (select name 
           from table
           where id > t.id
           order by id
           limit 1
          ) as next_person
from table t;
```

However, you didn't tag any `DBMS`, so i choosed the `subquery` with `limit` clause, but some of `DBMS` has not limit clause such as `SQL Server` so use `TOP` clause instead:

In SQL Server, you can use [`LEAD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function :

```
select *, lead(name) over (order by id) as next_person
from table t;
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't state your DBMS, but the following is ANSI standard SQL using window functions which are supported by all [modern DBMS](http://modern-sql.com/)

```
select id, 
       name, 
       registration_date, 
       lead(name) over (order by registration_date) as next_person
from the_table
order by registration_date;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query, it is working.

```
select 
  t1.name, 
  t1.registration_date as "registration date", 
  if(t2.name is null, '-', t2.name ) as "next person" 
from test as t1
left join test as t2 on t2.registration_date > t1.registration_date
group by t1.id
```